# Problem with Zend Project

Tags: php, zend-framework

i write a script and it works perfectly, on my local server.

I have uploaded it on my server and now I getting this Problem

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /homepages/46/d319011794/htdocs/suche/public/index.php on line 18

an here is my index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL || E_STRICT);

define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../application');

set_include_path(
 APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'
 . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../application/models'
 . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
);

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

new App_Connect();

try
{ //Line 18
 require '../application/bootstrap.php';
}
catch(Exception $exception)
{
 echo "<html><body>Fehler beim bootstraping";

 if(defined('APPLICATION_ENVIROMENT') && APPLICATION_EVIROMENT != 'production')
 {
  echo "<br><br>" . $exception->getMessage() . "<br>"
  . "<div align='left'>Stack Trace: "
  . "<pre> " . $exception->getTraceAsString() . "</pre></div>";
 }

 echo "</body></html>";
 exit(1);
}

Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

This is a Zend Project... so may be some one know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using on the server side?  Perhaps it's a PHP 4.x installation, which does not support exceptions.  This would seem like the most likely cause of the parse error.